# SSIS Package Error: Object cannot be cast to Empty

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

> Error: Executing the query "EXEC dbo.executeJob  @parentExecutionInstanceGUI..." failed with the following error: "Object cannot be cast to Empty.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Does anyone have ideas on why I am getting this error? It doesn't happen with every run. It happened on the first step of an 8 step SSA job that moves data between the data warehouse, the data mart, and several databases. That fist step executes package that ultimately executes two stored procedures that insert data into two tables.

I didn't write/create any of this - I have been tasked with figuring out why this error occurred and from there possibly figuring out how to keep it from happening again.

Comment: Are you using ApexSQL Data Diff?

Comment: No - not using ApexSQL Data Diff.